# can't install-plugin activiti in STS

Tags: java, grails, plugins, activiti

i am using sts3.3 and grails2.3.0, and i download a sample activiti project(activiti5121-g222-sample.zip) from https://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/downloads/list

after import the project i got this:

```
Command terminated with an exception: org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessDiedException: Grails process died (see details for partial output)
Grails process died
------System.out:-----------
 Loading Grails 2.3.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.12.1, org.activiti:activiti-spring:jar:5.12.1: Could not find artifact org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.12.1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.12.1, org.activiti:activiti-spring:jar:5.12.1: Could not find artifact org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.12.1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.12.1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact org.activiti:activiti-engine:jar:5.12.1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
------System.err:-----------
```

my BuildConfig.groovy is:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve true // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        mavenRepo "https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"


        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'

        compile ":activiti:5.12.1"
        compile ":activiti-spring-security:0.5.0"
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
    }
}
```

anyone know why?

Comment: I had the same problem as you, but I upgraded my Grails for release 2.3.1 and solved.